# I can't stop null from showing up in my output for my 1d array in java

Tags: java, arrays, nested-loops

I am struggling to declare i as an interger and I can't figure out why the output is coming out as null. The goal is to make a sequence
 My code is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] myArray = new String[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                myArray[i] = myArray[i] + "A";
            }
            System.out.println(myArray[i]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that none of the items inside the array has value, therefore they are `null`.
You can use the following code which initialize all item whith an empty string in the first loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    myArray[i] = "";
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
        myArray[i] = myArray[i] + "A";
    }
    System.out.println(myArray[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
String[] myArray = new String[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
        myArray[i] = myArray[i] + "A";
    }
    System.out.println(myArray[i]);
    }
}
```

At this line

> myArray[i] = myArray[i] + "A";

myArray[i] at the right side is null, so concatinating "A" with a null will make it null again. You should initialize each myArray[i] as Answered by Amir MB or can try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
String[] myArray = new String[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
        myArray[i] = "A" + myArray[i];
    }
    System.out.println(myArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: When a string is null and you concatenate it with another string, it will consider null as string so if you run your code you get: Anull, AAnull and so on.

Comment: I understand but the way I mentioned will show him the issue of null in string concatination as well. I confess your Answer is more appropriate :)

Comment: I'm not saying my answer is better, I just wanted to point out that changing the order of concatenation doesn’t solve the problem. You need an explicit initialization.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    myArray[i] = "";
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
        myArray[i] = myArray[i] + "A";
    }
    System.out.println(myArray[i]);
}


String[] myArray = new String[10];
```

This is an object array and all objects are initialized to null, if there is no explicit value assigned to it.

So, each element of the array needs to be assigned to a empty string; do it in the first for loop as mentioned above.

Or, assign values during array declaration itself. Worth for a small sized array, but won't recommend for a larger one.

```
String[] myArray = new String[]{"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""};
```

Arrays class has a fill method.

```
String[] myArray = new String[10];
Arrays.fill(myArray, "");
```